# Finding the highest COUNT in each GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to find the Max value for each group,
1st of all finding the count(*) of the groups which contain different series.

```
select count(*) cnt,f.org_name org_name ,e.err_type||'>>'||s.sub_type error 
     from MOE_OFFICE f ,MOE_COMPLAINT c ,MOE_ANSWERS a ,moe_error e ,moe_sub_error s 
       where f.MAIN_OFFICE=:F200_X 
         and f.ORG_ID     = c.com_to
         and c.com_id     = a.com_id 
         and a.err_id     = e.err_id
         and a.sub_id     = s.sub_id
         and e.err_id     = s.sub_err_id
       group by (e.err_type||'>>'||s.sub_type),f.org_name
having count(*) = ( select max(cnt) from 
 (select   count(*) cnt
     from MOE_OFFICE f ,MOE_COMPLAINT c ,MOE_ANSWERS a ,moe_error e ,moe_sub_error s 
       where f.MAIN_OFFICE=:F200_X 
         and f.ORG_ID     = c.com_to
         and c.com_id     = a.com_id 
         and a.err_id     = e.err_id
         and a.sub_id     = s.sub_id
         and e.err_id     = s.sub_err_id
        group by (e.err_type||'>>'||s.sub_type),f.org_name
   )
)    order by 1 desc
```

**note:-** F200_X is a dynamic variable can be 10 or 20 or 30

Comment: I can't possibly follow your query, please reformat (use edit button)

Comment: So your query doesn't work? Does it give an error or wrong values or nothing at all?

Comment: three columns those are :- count()    org_name    error

Comment: all records will be grouped based on (org_name and error ) ; for example

Comment: 144     office_1   err1   ;  28  office_2   err 6 ;  33 office_3  err11 ; 55 office_2  err 7

Comment: so, I hope to get the highest counting value for error types

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MAIN_QUERY AS
    (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
          , (E.ERR_TYPE || '>>' || S.SUB_TYPE) AS THE_ERROR
          , F.ORG_NAME
       FROM MOE_OFFICE F
          , MOE_COMPLAINT C
          , MOE_ANSWERS A
          , MOE_ERROR E
          , MOE_SUB_ERROR S 
      WHERE F.MAIN_OFFICE = :F200_X 
        AND F.ORG_ID = C.COM_TO
        AND C.COM_ID = A.COM_ID 
        AND A.ERR_ID = E.ERR_ID
        AND A.SUB_ID = S.SUB_ID
        AND E.ERR_ID = S.SUB_ERR_ID
      GROUP BY (E.ERR_TYPE || '>>' || S.SUB_TYPE)
          , F.ORG_NAME)
SELECT MAX(CNT)
     , THE_ERROR
     , ORG_NAME
  FROM MAIN_QUERY
 GROUP BY THE_ERROR
     , ORG_NAME
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
```